# Cannot add remote in git

Tags: git

Please, help me. I cannot add remote in my git repository. Where is my problem?

```
git remote add https://github.com/ProgrammingHeroWC4/warehouse-management-client-side-Nmakhdum.git

usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=(push|fetch)]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

Comment: It needs a _name_.

Comment: This is a *great* example of usage spew.  (git is notorious for this).  A useful error message would be something like "missing name", or "invalid name", or "missing url", or even "not enough arguments".  Printing the usage statement is not at all helpful.  Remember, every time you write code that prints a usage statements instead of an error message, a kitten dies.

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
```

You need two params: name and url.

```
git remote add originNew https://github.com/ProgrammingHeroWC4/warehouse-management-client-side-Nmakhdum.git
```

You are not adding all the required params and git shows you the help details for the command.

Answer (score 0):

Add Name
git remote add name_here https://github.com/ProgrammingHeroWC4/warehouse-management-client-side-Nmakhdum.git